# Adding helper function for both foundation and handlers

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to add an helper function to my yesod app that will "live" in a seperate file and could be imported in both foundation file and the handlers, i dont want to have reimport all the modules again. and i cant use the Import module because im getting circular dependencies ( Import -> helper -> foundation -> Import).

Answer (score 1):

The GHC manual has [a section on mutually recursive modules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#mutual-recursion).

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than messing around with mutually-recursive modules it might be better to just re-import all the stuff from Import that you want.

Comment: If im not wrong it wont be possible because i need the App datatype from the foundation file so i need the foundation file itself which will get me to the same circular dependencies problem.